# MapReduce how to check if the key exists in both tables left join

Tags: java, hadoop, join, mapreduce

I have 2 map methods that send this to my reducer

key/value

```
number1 value1
number2 value2
number3 value3
number4 value10
```

and
key/value

```
number1 value4
number2 value5
number5 value6
number6 value7
```

so the reducer receives them like this

```
number1 value1 value4
number2 value2 value5
number3 value3
number4 value10
number5 value6
number6 value7
```

How do I add to the context only the pairs whose value exists in table 1?

Maybe there is a way not to pass to the reducer these values?

```
number5 value6
number6 value7
```

and only pass these

```
number1 value1 value4
number2 value2 value5
number3 value3
number4 value10
```

I thought of adding a word to the begining of every value in table 1 and checking if it exists in the reducer like so

```
for (Text value: values) {
    String[] stringValue = value.toString().split(" ");
    if (stringValue[0].equals("checkValue")) {
        boo = 1;
```

but this doesn't work and the code has too many unnecessary `if else` blocks

```
public class Reduce extends Reducer<Text, Text, Text, Text> {
    UtilClass utilClass = new UtilClass();
    String result = "";
    Text theKey = null;
    int boo = 0;

    @Override
    public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<Text> values, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        String string = "";
        // send only date type values
        HashMap<Text, Integer> m = new HashMap<>();
        // Populate the HashMap
        for (Text value : values) {
            String[] stringValue = value.toString().split(" ");
            if (stringValue[0].equals("cdr")) {
                boo = 1;
                Text element = new Text(utilClass.getPeriod(stringValue[1] + " " + stringValue[2]));
                if (m.get(element) == null) {
                    m.put(element, 1);
                } else {
                    m.put(element, m.get(element) + 1);
                }
            } else {
                if (string.equals("")) {
                    string = stringValue[1] + " " + stringValue[2] + " " + stringValue[3];
                } else if (stringValue[4].equals("A") || stringValue[4].equals("S")) {
                    string = stringValue[1] + " " + stringValue[2] + " " + stringValue[3];
                }
            }
        }

        if (boo == 1) {
            // Display the frequencies
            for (Map.Entry<Text, Integer> entry : m.entrySet()) {
                if (theKey != key) {
                    result = "";
                    theKey = key;
                }
                result += entry.getValue() + "_" + entry.getKey() + " ";
            }

            // add BAN_KEY; MARKET_KEY_SRC;ACCOUNT_TYPE_KEY
            result = string + " " + result;

            // add rest for every entry
            context.write(key, new Text(result));
        } else {
            context.write(key, new Text(result));
        }
    }
}
```

I'm trying to left join these tables. I can't use hive and the rest.

Comment: can you load keys from table1 in memory?

Comment: @Adam you mean create a separate set/map that will hold those keys? That might work. I'll try.